# Revenuecat Flutter- Why introductory price not applied while making purchase?

Tags: flutter, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

In flutter, I am using revenuecat for handling google play subscriptions. When I do a test subscription to a package that has an introductory offer, the original price is shown to the google play subscription sheet, and no introductory offer is mentioned. And after the subscription is successful, the original price is shown in the billing email.

Any suggestions to apply introductory offer while purchasing product?